# WorksheetFunction.CountIf for multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am using  WorksheetFunction.CountIf to compare among two different work sheets but getting 1004 error

```
Sub sbWriteIntoCellData()
Dim CODE As Workbook
Dim Sheet1 As Sheets
Dim Sheet2 As Sheets
Set Sheet1 = Sheets
Set Sheet2 = Sheets
For Each rngCell In Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A2", range("A2").End(xlDown))

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").range("A2", range("A2").End(xlDown)), rngCell) = 1 Then

      Worksheets("Sheet1").range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "Yes"
        Else: Worksheets("Sheet1").range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "No"
    End If



Next

MsgBox "Execution completed"

End Sub
```

[[image]

Comment: If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").range("A2", range("A2").End(xlDown)), rngCell) = 1 Then
Getting error at this line

Comment: you need to specify a worksheet for **every** range. There are – range objects that are not tied to a specific worksheet. Also what do you expect `Set Sheet1 = Sheets` to do?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. Can you please explain with syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tidy up your code, use correct references and set your variables properly. Specify for every `Range` object in which sheet it is. Then you should not get any errors (of course I didn't check your code logic, but just corrected the obvious issues).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sbWriteIntoCellData()
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Sheet1.Range("A2", Sheet1.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A2", Sheet2.Range("A2").End(xlDown)), Cell.Value) = 1 Then
            Sheet1.Range("C" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Yes"
        Else
            Sheet1.Range("C" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "No"
        End If
    Next Cell

    MsgBox "Execution completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir... I bow my head to you patience.....
I am new to coding world and didn't even understand some basics.....
Thanks a lot for standing beside me in this heard journey...

Comment: The code is perfectly working for me... But when I try a large set around 500k(5-lakhs) set of records comparing with some 5000 (max count) it is executing very slow (Not responding even after 15 min) and i closed the excel forcefully...
Is there any way to cut the execution time... Please help

Comment: if it is v-lookup formula the execution time is less than 2 min for almost 1.2 million records comparing with 200 (even up to 5k) from different work books....   
The formula is mentioned below....
IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,'[Value Sets.xlsx]Value Sets'!$AE$2:$AE$130,1,FALSE))=FALSE,
ISNA(VLOOKUP(L2,'[Value Sets.xlsx]Value Sets'!$AE$2:$AE$130,1,FALSE))=FALSE,
ISNA(VLOOKUP(M2,'[Value Sets.xlsx]Value Sets'!$AE$2:$AE$130,1,FALSE))=FALSE,
ISNA(VLOOKUP(E2,'[Value Sets.xlsx]Value Sets'!$AE$2:$AE$130,1,FALSE))=FALSE),"Yes","No")

Comment: But it will execute in every single cell and i need to drag every time for different sets of data comparison.. This is why I am looking for a VBA code

Comment: If you can use formulas use formulas they are almost always faster than VBA.

Comment: Okay Sir... Is there a way to execute the same formula using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

I have generated a code to pass v-lookup formula into VBA and it is working fine...
I am posting my code(verified).. It might help some one who is looking for similar kind of solution

The code will work for comparing three different rows in sheet-1 with another row data in sheet-2 in or condition

Simply: Code will print "Yes" if the value in a2(sheet-2) exists in F2/H2/I2 from sheet-1
The result will be stored in AB2 in sheet-1

```
    Sub compare()
    Dim DataRange As Range
      Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
        Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
        Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
.Find the last cell value
     Dim Cell As Range
      Dim last As Double
    With ActiveSheet
            last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End With
       Range("AB2").Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(H2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE))=FALSE),""Yes"",""No"")"
    Range("AB2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2:AB" & last)
    MsgBox "Execution completed"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using R1C1 notation can both increase processing time and also make the code easier to maintain.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sbWriteIntoCellData()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With sht1

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

        Dim res As Range
        Set res = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)

        With res
                                                 '-2 bc formula on column C and checking against column A from sheet2
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=If(COUNTIF(Sheet2!C[-2],RC[-2])>1,""Yes"",""No"")"
            .Calculate
            .Value = .Value
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey one small question... Can we include dynamic range in the v lookup formula instead of $A$2:$A$5